# pygame displays blank white screen

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm new to pygame. Installed it successfully and displayed a window. However, I couldn't get it to run anything beyond this. Background colors are not changing, lines are not drawn. Nothing. Window just stays open with white screen. I've used an example program to check if its running still I got the same results, a blank white window. Here is the code that I used.

```
import pygame as pg
import random

if __name__ == '__main__':
    running = True
    pg.init()
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((600, 400))
    screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    timer = 0
    bg = (random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(
        0, 255), random.randint(0, 255))

    while running:
        screen.fill(bg)
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                running = False

        if pg.time.get_ticks()-timer > 1000:
            timer = pg.time.get_ticks()
            bg = (random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(
                0, 255), random.randint(0, 255))
        pg.display.update()
        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)
```

can I get some help please? Is there anything wrong in my installation?

Comment: window *is* changing color on my machine (MacOS X Python2.7), might be something unique in your configuration.

Comment: could be. How can I check that? I'm running this on Python 3. I've tried changing the Visual Studio Code Interpreter to 2.7 but looks like pygame is installed only for python 3

Comment: Installed pygame for 2.7 as well and tried. Still the same results, a blank white window. I don't know what am I missing.

Comment: you shouldn't have to change the python version, best to keep using `python 3.x`. what version of pygame you have installed? `print(pg.__version__)`

Comment: The latest version 1.9.4

Comment: maybe run a full test of `pygame` package and see if anything is missing? try running this code and check results: `import pygame.tests;
pygame.tests.run()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181506/discussion-between-kunaguvarun-and-davedwards).